# Android unable to send text to another device

Tags: android, sms

I have checked already posted solutions for the error which advised the I put in the permissions check.

Using targetSdkVersion 26 - and Android Studio 3.2

I set up (from a youtube tutorial) a sms within my application.  I have two apps on two separate devices.  I want the users from App A to be able to talk to the users of App B.  I put the same code in both apps from this tutorial

[Sending and Receiving Messages or SMS - Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGnEEvCo1lM)

At first, when I run the app, I got an error:

```
Sending SMS Message: uid 10085 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS
```

So, I added a permissions check in the button onclick()

Now, when I run the apps, nothing happens when trying to send.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RiderActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MessageReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**SMS_Activity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // display the message in the textView
        TextView inTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMsg);
        inTxt.setText(intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
    }
};


btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myMsg = tvMessage.getText().toString();
            String theNumber = tvNumber.getText().toString();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SMS_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is not granted
            } else {
                sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);
            }
        }
    });


protected void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {

    String SENT = "Message Sent";
    String DELIVERED = "Message Delivered";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new
            Intent(SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg, sentPI, null);
}
```

### Edit

**Added onRequestPermissionsResult:**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (permissions[0].equalsIgnoreCase
                    (Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted.
            } else {
                // Permission denied. Stop the app.
                Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.failure_permission));
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        getString(R.string.failure_permission),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated btnSend.setOnClickListener:**

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myMsg = tvMessage.getText().toString();
            String theNumber = tvNumber.getText().toString();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SMS_Activity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is not granted
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SMS_Activity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 1);
                sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);
            }
        }
    });
```

### Edit #2

As recommended, I followed this tutorial:

[Android Apps - Phone Calls and SMS](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-phone-sms-course/content/Lesson%201/1_c_phone_calls.html)

giving me this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10085 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
```

I then made these changes:

AndroidManifest - added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

SMSActivity - added:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 2;
```

... checkforPermissions() // runs at onCreate and before smsManager

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.permission_not_granted));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.permission_not_granted));

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);

        }

    } else {
        // Permission already granted. Enable the SMS button.
        enableSmsButton();
    }
```

... onRequestPermissionsResult()

```
// Check if permission is granted or not for the request.
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
            if (permissions[0].equalsIgnoreCase
                    (Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Permission was granted. Enable sms button.
                enableSmsButton();

            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.failure_permission));
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        getString(R.string.failure_permission),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Disable the sms button.
                disableSmsButton();
            }
        }

        break;

        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
            if (permissions[0].equalsIgnoreCase
                    (Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // Permission was granted. Enable sms button.
                enableSmsButton();

            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.failure_permission));
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        getString(R.string.failure_permission),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Disable the sms button.
                disableSmsButton();
            }
        }

        break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Now, when I run the apps, I get the same error as above.

**SOLUTION RESOLVED**

SMSACTIVITY

```
private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

    int permissionSendSms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    int permissionReceiveSms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    int permissionReadPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionSendSms != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    }

    if (permissionReceiveSms != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
    }

    if (permissionReadPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new
                String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
            // Check if permission is granted or not for the request.
            if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults == null) {
                /*If result is null*/
                disableSmsButton();

            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                /*If We accept permission*/
                if (getIntent() != null) {
                    phone_no = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");
                    Log.e(TAG, "phoneNo = " + phone_no);


                }

                enableSmsButton();

            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                /*If We Decline permission*/
                disableSmsButton();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works great now!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your app doesn't have SMS permission granted, so it's running `// Permission is not granted`, which is a rather uneventful line of code. You can ask for permission using the ActivityCompat API with

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this,
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
    1
);
```

You can catch this event with a [onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])), and then either continue like normal if they gave you access, or show a Toast or something if they denied access.

Comment: where in my code would I put this line? where it says // Permission is not granted? and what does the 1 refer to?

Comment: @LizG Yes, where your `// Permission is not granted` is

Comment: @LizG That number gets sent to your `onRequestPermissionsResult`, so you can use it as an identifier. I just have it a random number. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)). Instead of 1, you can use something like `SEND_SMS_PERM_REQUEST`

Comment: so the number should be declared above with the properties ? oh ok I don't have an onRequestPermissionsResult :|

Comment: @LizG Yeah, you'll have to add it. For now, just add those 5 lines in my answer and on your app, hit allow. The onRequestPermissionsResult is just handle a deny case or update the app in the case of allow. The exact problem you're trying to solve has been done [here](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-phone-sms-course/content/Lesson%202/2_p_sending_sms_messages.html), so you can check that out for supplemental info

Comment: @LizG Or, to give the app permission on your device, you can go to Settings > Apps > YourApp > Permissions, and grant it SMS permission. Of course, you probably want to prompt your user as opposed to making them figure that out.

Comment: yes, exactly... I would have nothing to do with their settings

Comment: I added the onRequestPermissionsResult as "EDIT".  When I click on SEND, I get the error: java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10085 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

Comment: I referred to the tutorial you suggested and coming up with this error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10085 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
at this line: smsManager.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, smsMessage, sentIntent, deliveryIntent);

Comment: did that as well, should I display?

Comment: What does display mean?

Comment: Sorry, should I put display in this thread my permissions as I have in my app so you can see it?

Comment: Sure? idk what you mean by "display"

Comment: see edit #2.  If there is anything else I need to add, just let me know.

Comment: @LizG Are you sure it's impossible to send a text msg without `enableSmsButton`? You must be executing `sendTextMessage` before you asked for and got both permissions. Are you getting the dialog option on your phone? Your switch case doesn't look good, you're executing `enableSmsButton` after getting only one permission. But what if _both_ SEND_SMS and READ_PHONE_STATE are false? Then you called `enableSmsButton` after only one of them was resolved.

Comment: so what do you suggest?  I don't even know why its asking for READ PHONE STATE, I am not using the PHONE

Comment: @LizG `sendTextMessage` requires it. `READ_PHONE_STATE` allows things like getting your phone number, which might be necessary when sending a text

Comment: @LizG Do not call `sendTextMessage` without getting those permissions. Idk what your code is doing, put debug statements before each `sendTextMessage` call if you must. Just make sure those debug statements aren't printing unless you already hit "Allow" on your phone using the methods described above.

Comment: @LizG Also, fix your switch-case. Don't `enableSmsButton` because the user granted a single permission. Make sure all permissions are granted before `enableSmsButton`.